# How can I access the SHA for a tree in git?

Tags: git

I am trying to get the SHA for a particular tree in my git repository. For example, If my working directory structure is like:

```
top_directory:
--File1
--File2
--Dir1
```

I like to have one command that gives me the SHA for the tree in Dir1 so that I can use it in a script.

My ultimate goal is to compare Dir1 with a remote branch. So, if you know how to do that directly, that is even better.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I like to take the resulting SHA and use it in a diff to compare it with a remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

given you are under top_directory, below will show your SHA for `Dir1`, if you want to recursively show the sub trees, just add `-r` option

```
git ls-tree HEAD Dir1
```

Comment: This is great. Is there a way I can feed the SHA to a diff command directly? What I am trying to do is to diff this tree against another remote branch.

Comment: well, you can use `cut` or `sed` or any text editor tool to grab the SHA. to feed to another command, you'd better to write a shell to make it clear